# Check if the following fields are conservative and solve the integrals

Tags: calculus, vector-fields, line-integrals

Let $L$ be the straight section connecting the points $A\left(0,-3,-6\right) \rightarrow B\left(3,2,1\right)$

Solve the following integrals (Check if the fields are conservative to avoid unnecessary work)

$\displaystyle \int_{L}
   \left( 9 x^2 y^2 z           \right) \; dx
 + \left( 6 x^3 y z + 12 y^2 z \right) \; dy
 + \left( 3 x^3 y^2 + 4 y^3   \right) \; dz  {}$
$\displaystyle \int_{L}
  \left( 9x^{2}y^{2}z \right) \; dx +
  \left( 3x+6x^{3}yz+12y^{2}z \right) \; dy +
  \left( 3x^{3}y^{2}-3y+4y^{3} \right) \; dz  {}$

1. What unnecessary work can be avoided if the field is conservative?
2. I started by calculating the curl to check if the field is conservative. In the first integral the curl is 0. Is this suffiecient to say the field is conservative?
3. If the field is not conservative what method do I use to solve the integral?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For conservative vector field, the line integral over a smooth curve starting at point $A$ and ending at point $B$ is path independent and can be evaluated as,

$\displaystyle \int_C \vec{F} \cdot dr = f(B) - f(A) \,$

where $\vec{F} = \nabla f(x, y, z)$ i.e. $\vec{F} \, $ is the gradient of the potential function $f(x, y, z)$.

For your first line integral,

$\displaystyle \int_{L}
   \left( 9 x^2 y^2 z           \right) \; dx
 + \left( 6 x^3 y z + 12 y^2 z \right) \; dy
 + \left( 3 x^3 y^2 + 4 y^3   \right) \; dz  {}$

The vector field is $\vec{F} = (9 x^2 y^2 z, 6 x^3 y z + 12 y^2 z, 3 x^3 y^2 + 4 y^3)$

As you have already established that the curl is zero, to find the potential function

$f(x, y ,z) = \int F_x dx + g(y, z) = 3x^3y^2z + g(y, z)$

Now if you look at $F_y$, you see the second term as only a function of $y, z$. Integrating that, $g(y, z) = 4y^3z + h(z)$

As there is no term in $F_z$ which is only a function of $z$,

$f(x, y, z) = 3x^3y^2z + 4y^3z$

Your line integral is simply = $f(3, 2, 1) - f(0, -3, -6)$.

While your second vector field is not conservative, you can easily split it into two and take advantage of the work we already did.

$\displaystyle I_2 = I_1 + 3 \int_{L} x \, dy - y \, dz \,$ (if $I_1$ is the line integral from the first problem).

Specifically on your question on parametrization of line segment $AB$,

$r(t) = (0, -3, -6) + t \, (3-0, 2 - (-3), (1 - (-6))$

$ = (0, -3, -6) + (3, 5, 7) t, 0 \leq t \leq 1$

$x = 3t, y = -3 + 5t, z = -6 + 7t$

$dx = 3 \, dt, dy = 5 \, dt, z = 7 \, dt$

Comment: Thank you! How does the process differ for a non-conservative vector field?

Comment: You will have to parametrize your curve $r(t)$ then take its derivative and do a dot product with the vector field and integrate over the curve.

Comment: On your first point, should I give you the link of a question on the site where the vector field is not conservative and we had to integrate to find the line integral?

Comment: Yes I would appreciate that thank you.

Comment: Another point you should note. The second vector field does not seem conservative but it is really your first vector field plus additional terms. So you can split your second integral into two.

Comment: Here is an example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3942249/evaluate-the-line-integral-of-the-square-c/3942863#3942863. Let me know if you get stuck anywhere.

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how to use green's theorem for a three dimensional vector field

Comment: This question is not a line integral on a closed path. So we cannot apply green's theorem.

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you can give me an example of a parametrization that wouldn't make the solution too complicated, also once everything becomes in terms of t what limits would I use for the integral?

Comment: Also do you mean that in this specific case the second integral is simply the first integral + the extra terms $ \int 3x dy + \int -3y dz$ ?

Comment: I will try that thank you!